# Create Hyperlink in PDF document using xsl fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am generating a PDF from XML using xsl fo and Java.I need to embed a hyperlink in one column of my 6 column table. Here is my code snippet.

```
    <fo:table-row>
    <xsl:for-each select="./clientMain/hierarchy/link">
    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="left" font-size="10pt"><fo:block>Hierarchy</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="left" font-size="9pt">
    <fo:block><a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@link"/></xsl:attribute>
    </a></fo:block>
    <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="@link"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-row>
```

But my program fails with this error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-row" is missing child elements. Required content model: (table-cell+) (No context info available)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:718)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2336)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:682)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2336)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:682)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2336)
```

If I comment this row all works fine. Please HELP !!!!

Comment: Please show a bit more of the input xml... Might it be that the xpath `./clientMain/hierarchy/link` does not match anything? does the link element have a `link` attribute or what is the exact structure? Also, I'm not sure if adding a href attribute to a block makes it an xsl-fo hyperlink, maybe you check a bit in the xsl-fo spec/doc.

Comment: if there is no node detected by the `xsl:for-each`, you will end up with a table row with no table cell, thus the error.

Answer (score 5):

Not a solution to the 'fo:table-row" is missing child elements' error, but:

Looking at your code, I expect the links won't work. Instead of the `<a>` tag, use `<fo:basic-link internal-destination="@link" color="blue">`.

This assumes @link contains a reference to an ID somewhere in the PDF.

For external links, use `<fo:basic-link external-destination="url">`

Comment: I think to make it appear like a link some text decoration should be done as well 
<fo:basic-link external-destination="url" color="blue" text-decoration="underline"></fo:basic-link>